# Android/Java Send a http post request with chars not reformatted as UTF-8

Tags: java, android, utf-8, network-programming, utf

In an Android app I need to use a http post request to talk to a D-Link W215. I'm basically making a java version o fthe code found here: http://www.devttys0.com/2014/05/hacking-the-d-link-dsp-w215-smart-plug/. The problem is that one of the bytes I need to send is 0xAC and when it is sent over the network through java, it is received as unicode character \00ac which are hex characters 0xC2 0xAC. Is there a way to have byte 0xAC actually sent. Thanks.

Edit: I also have confirmed that the problem is when the bytes are sent as the data is correct when I check it before I send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
byte[] message = {0xAC};
Socket socket = ...
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dOut.write(message);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to send a full http post request. There is a server running on the W215 that I'm communicating with.

Comment: Convert the http post request string into the byte array and feed your byte at the specific position.

Comment: Ok, I did it but the message is still sent wrong. You can see an example here:http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2016/08/29/POST_TEST_GG/16.12.36518986871. The last line contains the characters: �@\Â¬ where they should be: �@\¬.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally got it working with your example.